# How to refresh INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS?

Tags: mysql, sql

One of the application that we have written uses `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table to fetch the column details. We use that information to create dynamic insert script for different tables available in our DB.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME as columnName, DATA_TYPE as dataType
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'XYZ_TABLE'
```

Recently I updated column of one of the table. But same information didn't get reflected in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

How can the data in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` can be refreshed when there is a change in table schema?

Comment: No need to do anything. INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS gives the updated column names always.

Comment: did you manually check that they are updated or not?

Comment: question you mentioned here and solution you found is not related to each other(totally different) @Soumyajit Swain

Comment: If the isolation level is REPEATABLE READ, it will always give the same value. The new changes won't be reflected.But the change will be there in the disk. Is there some work around for REPEATABLE READ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issues and the culprit was isolation level. I have set my isolation level to repeatable.INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a in-memory db. It reads the data from log and create the table. I was always looking at the old record till I create a new MYSQL session.

For more detail , Go to [understanding_INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/understanding-the-mysql-information-schema-database.html)

Answer (score -4):

use SqlWorkbench ...its provide you graphical user interface..you can easily manage all the functioning